# deciphering "invalid mem access map_ptr" on BPF program upload

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf

I'm writing a custom application that reads C code, calls LLVM to generate BPF byte code from that C code, then relocates any bpf map symbols and uploads it to the kernel. I can successfully upload and run programs that don't use BPF maps, but as soon as I relocate a program to use a BPF map I get the following error:

```
invalid mem access 'map_ptr'
```

Details follow:

The following input is given to LLVM:

```
// Placeholder values for user-requested maps
void *a;

#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

int kprobe__blk_start_request(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
  long rq = PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
  u64 val = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
  bpf_map_update_elem(a, &rq, &val, BPF_ANY);
  return 0;
}
```

which generates the following bytecode

```
Found function: kprobe__blk_start_request
  size: 120 bytes
  addr: 0
relocate: a @ 32

/tmp/bpf7990/bpf.o: file format ELF64-BPF

Disassembly of section .text:
kprobe__blk_start_request:
       0:   79 11 70 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 + 112)
       1:   7b 1a f8 ff 00 00 00 00     *(u64 *)(r10 - 8) = r1
       2:   85 00 00 00 05 00 00 00     call 5
       3:   7b 0a f0 ff 00 00 00 00     *(u64 *)(r10 - 16) = r0
       4:   18 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = 0ll
       6:   79 11 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 + 0)
       7:   bf a2 00 00 00 00 00 00     r2 = r10
       8:   07 02 00 00 f8 ff ff ff     r2 += -8
       9:   bf a3 00 00 00 00 00 00     r3 = r10
      10:   07 03 00 00 f0 ff ff ff     r3 += -16
      11:   b7 04 00 00 00 00 00 00     r4 = 0
      12:   85 00 00 00 02 00 00 00     call 2
      13:   b7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     r0 = 0
      14:   95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     exit
```

and the "a" symbol gets relocated in instruction #4 as follows:

```
Relocating instruction 4
    from code:0x18 dst_reg:1 src_reg:0 off:0x0 imm:0x0
      to code:0x18 dst_reg:1 src_reg:1 off:0x0 imm:0x4
kprobe__blk_start_request:
       0:   79 11 70 00 00 00 00 00 
       1:   7b 1a f8 ff 00 00 00 00 
       2:   85 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 
       3:   7b 0a f0 ff 00 00 00 00 
       4:   18 11 00 00 04 00 00 00 
       5:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
       6:   79 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 
       7:   bf a2 00 00 00 00 00 00 
       8:   07 02 00 00 f8 ff ff ff 
       9:   bf a3 00 00 00 00 00 00 
      10:   07 03 00 00 f0 ff ff ff 
      11:   b7 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 
      12:   85 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 
      13:   b7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
      14:   95 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The "04" in instruction #4 is the FD to the map for symbol "a".
After calling BPF_PROG_LOAD I get the following in the error log from the kernel.

```
Failed to load kprobe__blk_start_request BPF code
0: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
0: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 +112)
1: R1=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
1: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -8) = r1
2: R1=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
2: (85) call bpf_ktime_get_ns#5
3: R0=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
3: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r0
4: R0=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
4: (18) r1 = 0xffff88042be0b000
6: R0=inv(id=0) R1=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=8,vs=8) R10=fp0
6: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)
R1 invalid mem access 'map_ptr'

Errno: 13 (Permission denied)
```

I'm having trouble deciphering this error log. What is the kernel trying to tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Error explanation

`invalid mem access 'map_ptr'` means you're trying to read from an invalid memory location, in particular one pointed to by a map pointer.

Indeed, referring to your bytecode:

```
   4:   18 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = 0ll
   6:   79 11 00 00 00 00 00 00     r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 + 0)
```

you first load an immediate value inside r1, then read the memory location pointed to by r1. However, the kernel verifier identifies BPF_LD_IMM instructions as map pointer loading. So, [it tags r1 with the `map_ptr` type](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.13/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L3802). **The verifier then rejects instruction #6 [because it tries to read the memory location pointed to by the map pointer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.13/source/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L1731)** (you're only supposed to pass it to map helpers, not use it otherwise in BPF programs).

Basically, instruction #6 is both invalid and unneeded. Without it, your program should pass the verifier.

---

#### Likely fix

I don't have your relocation code so I can't reproduce, but I'd guess this invalid bytecode as to do with how you declare the map. If you take a look at [BPF samples in the Linux kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.13/source/samples/bpf/test_map_in_map_kern.c#L18), you'll see that **maps are usually declared as global structure to which the first map helper argument points**:

```
// Placeholder values for user-requested maps
struct bpf_map_def a = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
    .key_size = sizeof(u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(int),
    .max_entries = 1024,
};

#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

int kprobe__blk_start_request(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
  long rq = PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
  u64 val = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
  bpf_map_update_elem(&a, &rq, &val, BPF_ANY);
  return 0;
}
```